# AuthKit: server side verification of idToken falls short

Tags: gnosis-safe, web3auth

I need to verify users on my backend, trying to follow https://web3auth.io/docs/pnp/features/server-side-verification/social-login-users
but cannot get `app_scoped_privkey` , it always turns up undefined for some reason.

Seems like the [AA Safe demo repo](https://github.com/5afe/account-abstraction-demo-ui) is not using the same flow as the web3auth docs suggest. Tried to hack the code so as to follow the steps on web3auth docs but Im getting `undefined` instead of the `app_scoped_privkey`

Edit: just for clarification, this works fine when Im using web3auth library directly, which should mean that my process for deriving the private key is correct. Seems to be an issue with Safe's wrapper around their library, perhaps out of date dependencies?